Best way to handle optionally printing between unicode characters or ascii in C?
I am writing a rendering library for the terminal in C, to simplify things so far I have defined a "pixel" in the terminal like the following:
typedef struct tgl__term_pixel {
    char value;
    tgl__color_t foreground_color;
    tgl__color_t background_color;
} tgl__term_pixel_t;

However I understand that I am limiting my users to only ASCII characters by doing so.
I don't want to do that, so to handle this problem I thought maybe I can define a macro like so:
#ifndef TGL_TERM_PIXEL_T
#define TGL_TERM_PIXEL_T char
#endif

and redefine the "pixel" type like so:
typedef struct tgl__term_pixel {
    TGL_TERM_PIXEL_T value;
    tgl__color_t foreground_color;
    tgl__color_t background_color;
} tgl__term_pixel_t;

I could allow the user the define the type of value themselves before including the library if they so want to, or just leave it be limited to ASCII.
However this approach comes with the problem of printing values, how can I handle all the cases appropriatly, like if the user defines char* as the value type, I'll need to figure out a way to switch from putchar to fputs for example.
What do you think is the best way to approach this problem, am I on the right track?

In my opinion (hence a comment, not an answer), the best way to approach this is to ignore the ASCII requirement and only deal with UTF-8.  A UTF-8 code point can always be encoded in a 4 byte or less array and ASCII characters are a subset of that.

However, be careful of decomposed characters: as an example, ñ can be encoded as U+006E followed by U+0303 or as U+00F1. The former takes two UTF-8 code points. The latter only takes up one.

@JeremyP I think you meant Unicode code points, not UTF-8 code points.

@JeremyP yea the decomposed character problem is what I'm most concerned about, what if someone wanted to print an emoji with a skintone? would ruin the entire 4byte approach

Dynamically malloc a string of the needed length instead of using a fixed size.

A fixed maximum-size would sometimes be simpler and faster, depending on what is the use case.

@aboude You could either use Shawn's or Neil's approach. It's a case of whether you want to prioritise simplicity or memory use.

@JeremyP will try both
